# How are Iterators Created?

Tags: java, collections, iterator

A common approach to create an `Iterator` is :

```
Iterator iter = myarray.iterator();
```

Can anybody tell me how iter is created without new operator?
I know `Iterator` is an interface, so who implements it?

Comment: wow! guys you are Magic! :) thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look inside the implementation of `iterator()`, there'll be a `new` inside there, somewhere. For example, this is the `iterator()` method from OpenJDK's [`ArrayList`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/00cd9dc3c2b5/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java):

```
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return new Itr();
}
```

In turn, `Itr` refers to a private inner class that implements the `Iterator` interface:

```
private class Itr implements Iterator<E> {
    // implementation details
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You haven't shown what `myarray` is, but that's the key to finding the implementation. For example, if `myarray` refers to an `ArrayList` at execution time, then it'll call `ArrayList.iterator()` which will return an instance of the private `ArrayList.Itr` class. (At least in the JRE implementation I happened to look at.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. now I know how "myarray.iterator().hasNext();" works !

Answer (score 4):

Here's the code snippet from the [ArrayList](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html) class for that part. As you can see, there is an internal private class that implements the interface `Iterator` and an instance of this class is returned.

```
  766       /**
  767        * Returns an iterator over the elements in this list in proper sequence.
  768        *
  769        * <p>The returned iterator is <a href="#fail-fast"><i>fail-fast</i></a>.
  770        *
  771        * @return an iterator over the elements in this list in proper sequence
  772        */
  773       public Iterator<E> iterator() {
  774           return new Itr();
  775       }
  776   
  777       /**
  778        * An optimized version of AbstractList.Itr
  779        */
  780       private class Itr implements Iterator<E> {
  781           int cursor;       // index of next element to return
  782           int lastRet = -1; // index of last element returned; -1 if no such
  783           int expectedModCount = modCount;
  784   
  785           public boolean hasNext() {
  786               return cursor != size;
  787           }
  788   
  789           @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  790           public E next() {
  791               checkForComodification();
  792               int i = cursor;
  793               if (i >= size)
  794                   throw new NoSuchElementException();
  795               Object[] elementData = ArrayList.this.elementData;
  796               if (i >= elementData.length)
  797                   throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
  798               cursor = i + 1;
  799               return (E) elementData[lastRet = i];
  800           }
  801   
  802           public void remove() {
  803               if (lastRet < 0)
  804                   throw new IllegalStateException();
  805               checkForComodification();
  806   
  807               try {
  808                   ArrayList.this.remove(lastRet);
  809                   cursor = lastRet;
  810                   lastRet = -1;
  811                   expectedModCount = modCount;
  812               } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
  813                   throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
  814               }
  815           }
  816   
  817           final void checkForComodification() {
  818               if (modCount != expectedModCount)
  819                   throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
  820           }
  821       }
```

Answer (score 1):

`myarray.iterator` is a function.  The `new` operator only applies to types.  As [Mr. Skeet stated in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10863578/41747), the return value is likely an inner class that implements `Iterator` and the implementation of the `iterator()` method calls `new` on the inner class.

Answer (score 0):

An iterator is generally implemented as a private inner class of a data structure so that its methods can be written to suitably iterate over that structure's data. So the iterator will only be accessible through a method provided by the data structure class, in your case

```
myarray.iterator();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all class of object from `myarray` reference must implement interface `Iterable`. It means that class must add implementation to `Iterator iterator()` method.

To make things easy iterator() method returns object of private inner class implementing `Iterator` interface. It is done this way because *inner classes have acces to all fieldss of outer classes* (even private).

Here is example of reverse array iterator

```
class ReverseArray implements Iterable{
    private Object[] data;// some data to iterate
    public ReverseArray(Object[] data) {
        this.data=data;
    }
    private class ReverseIterator implements Iterator {
        int counter = data.length;

        public boolean hasNext() {
            if(counter>0)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        public Object next() {
            return data[--counter];
        }

        public void remove() {
            //TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }

    public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
        return new ReverseIterator();
    }
}
```

Lets test it

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ReverseArray reverseArray=new ReverseArray(new Integer[]{1,2,3,4,5});
        for(Object i:reverseArray)
            System.out.print(i+"; ");
        //OUT: 5; 4; 3; 2; 1;  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterator is an interface and it already implemented with every implementation of **List** interface like **ArrayList, Vector, LinkedList** and others you do not need to worry about its implementation just use it.

Comment: I think I need to worry a bit at some points, otherwise I will not learn the coding and how it works :)

Answer (score 0):

The collection classes from the standard library that implement `Iterable` interface usually have an inner class that extends `Iterator`, though that's not an requirement. You can subclass and instantiate `Iterator` anywhere you want, just like any other classes.

Here is an example from my utils where I have written a method that provides an `Iterable` instance for the given array.

```
public static Iterable<A> asIterable(final A[] xs) {
  return new Iterable<A>() {
    @Override
    public Iterator<A> iterator() {
      return new Iterator<A>() {
        private int i = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
          return i < xs.length;
        }

        @Override
        public A next() {
          A x = xs[i];
          i++;
          return x;
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
          throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
            "Cannot remove an element from an array.");
        }
      };
    }
  };
}
```